Forming $PDE$ of $z=e^yf\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)+e^xg(xy)$


Form the $PDE$ of $$z=e^yf\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)+e^xg(xy)$$
Where $f,g$ are arbitrary functions.


My try:
I let $w=e^yf\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)$ and $v=e^xg(xy)$.
Then after some calculus I got
$$w_y+\frac{x}{y}w_x=w$$ and $$v_x-\frac{y}{x}v_y=v$$
Then I added both, we get
$$w_y+v_x+\frac{x}{y}w_x-\frac{y}{x}v_y=z$$
Here $w_x=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$ and so on.
Any help how to proceed?

(Partial answer)
You are on the right track, however you will need to find a second-order PDE, because two characteristic lines are hidden behind this function actually, namely $xy = const$ and $x/y = const$, or equivalently $\ln x \pm \ln y = const$, which are thus described by the equation $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \pm\frac{y}{x}$ and associated to the operators $D_\pm = x\partial_x \pm y\partial_y$, with $D_+f(x/y) = D_-g(xy) = 0$.
The present characteristic curves imply a hyperbolic PDE, whose structure will be given by $x^2z_{xx} - y^2z_{yy} + \text{lower-order terms} = 0$ or similarly $D_+D_-z + \text{lower-order terms} = 0$. You may also make a change of variables of the form $\xi(x,y) = \phi(xy)$, $\eta(x,y) = \psi(x/y)$.
Finally, it is to be noted that it is quite straightforward to construct higher-order PDEs by hand by trying to annihilate the components of $z$. For example, the equation $((D_--x)^2-1)(D_--x)(D_+-y)z = 0$ does the job.
